# Jquery multiple table filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply multiple filters to table using Jquery with checkboxes.  I would like to filter on the Location and Age column.  The location filter is working correctly.  For example, checking the "East" checkbox will only show rows that have cities mapped to "East".

I also need to filter the age column, and have a checkbox which if checked, should hide "Unknown" ages.  This filter should be applied in addition to the Location filter.  Ex. Checking "Hide Unknown Ages" and "East" should only show people in the east region that have ages. I am storing the state of the checkbox as a boolean values, but I'm having trouble implementing this in code.  I'm thinking of checking the boolean value and branching the code before (if (cities == ""), but think this will lead to a lot of repeated code.  JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjfxgkon/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Map regions to cities
    const regions = {
        'central': ['Chicago', 'Madison', 'Dallas'],
        'east': ['New York', 'Boston'],
        'west': ['Seattle', 'Los Angeles'],
    }

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var locations = [];
        var hideNoAges = $('#hideAge').is(":checked")

        // Get ids of each region checkbox checked
        $(".location:input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                locations.push($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        })

        // Get list of all cities to be included in filter
        var cities = locations.map(function (i) { return regions[i].join(); }).join().split(",");

        // Branch code here? if (!hideNoAges)..... else.......
        if (cities == "") {// if no filters selected, show all items
            $("#indexTable tbody tr").show();
        } else { // otherwise, hide everything...
            $("#indexTable tbody tr").hide();

            $("#indexTable tbody tr").each(function () {
                var show = false;
                var row = $(this);
                //show only rows that match city name
                cities.forEach(function (city) {
                    if (row.find('td').eq(1).text() == city) { show = true; }
                })
                if (show) { row.show(); }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="indexTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Bob</td>
                <td>Chicago</td>
                <td>24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mike</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>Unknown</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sarah</td>
                <td>Seattle</td>
                <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill</td>
                <td>Los Angeles</td>
                <td>51</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gary</td>
                <td>Boston</td>
                <td>37</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Melissa</td>
                <td>Madison</td>
                <td>Unknown</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Greg</td>
                <td>Dallas</td>
                <td>61</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h5>Age Filter</h5>
    <label for="hideAge">Hide unknown ages</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hideAge">
    <h5>Region Filter</h5>
    <div>
        <label for="east">East</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="east" class="location">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="central">Central</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="central" class="location">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="west">West</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="west" class="location">
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Map regions to cities
  const regions = {
    'central': ['Chicago', 'Madison', 'Dallas'],
    'east': ['New York', 'Boston'],
    'west': ['Seattle', 'Los Angeles'],
  }

  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var locations = [];
    var hideNoAges = $('#hideAge').is(":checked")

    // Get ids of each region checkbox checked
    $(".location:input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        locations.push($(this).attr('id'));
      }
    })

    // Get list of all cities to be included in filter
    var cities = locations.map(function(i) {
      return regions[i].join();
    }).join().split(",");

    if (cities == "" && !hideNoAges) { // if no filters selected, show all items
      $("#indexTable tbody tr").show();
    } else { // otherwise, hide everything...
      $("#indexTable tbody tr").hide();

      $("#indexTable tbody tr").each(function() {
        var show = false;
        var row = $(this);

        if (hideNoAges) {
          if (row.find('td').eq(2).text() == "Unknown") {
            show = false;
          } else {
            show = true;
            if (cities != "") {
              cities.forEach(function(city) {
                if (row.find('td').eq(1).text() != city) {
                  show = false;
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }

        cities.forEach(function(city) {
          if (row.find('td').eq(1).text() == city) {
            show = true;
            if (hideNoAges && row.find('td').eq(2).text() == "Unknown") {
              show = false;
            }
          }
        })
        if (show) {
          row.show();
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="indexTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Bob</td>
          <td>Chicago</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mike</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>Unknown</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sarah</td>
          <td>Seattle</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bill</td>
          <td>Los Angeles</td>
          <td>51</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gary</td>
          <td>Boston</td>
          <td>37</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Melissa</td>
          <td>Madison</td>
          <td>Unknown</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Greg</td>
          <td>Dallas</td>
          <td>61</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <h5>Age Filter</h5>
    <label for="hideAge">Hide unknown ages</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hideAge">
    <h5>Region Filter</h5>
    <div>
      <label for="east">East</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="east" class="location">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="central">Central</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="central" class="location">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="west">West</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="west" class="location">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works well.  I have one more feature I'm trying to implement if you would be so kind to look at.  I'm trying to add a search box that will search through the rows currently showing.  It's works currently by itself, and I'm trying to have it work also with the filters in place.  I don't know if there is a simple solution (searching only through visible rows?), or if I have to account for all the filters again.  JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L09u3z4p/